# How to make a program which will output name and id as 2 different strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I need to make a program that will ask the user for his name and id as 1 string, and after provide a separate name and id. For example:

Enter the student info: Kobe Bean Bryant 51012345.

Student name is: Kobe Bean Bryant

Student ID is: 51012345

I tried it by myself, getting a different output, such as:

Student name is: Kobe Bean Bryant

Student ID is:&@

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int getNameAndID(char nameid[]) {
    char name[50];
    char id[50];
    bool notnumber=true;
    int i=0;
    for (i; nameid[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        if (nameid[i] >= '0' && nameid[i] <= '9') {
            notnumber = false;
        }
        if (notnumber) {
            name[i] = nameid[i];
        }
        else if (!notnumber) {
            id[i] = nameid[i];
        }
        
    }
    cout << "Student name is: " << name;
    cout << "\nStudent ID is: " << id;

}
int main() {
    cout << "Enter the student information: ";
    char a[50];
    cin.getline(a, 50);
    getNameAndID(a);

}
```

Still some problem with ID.
Can't understand what is wrong, please help me:(

(Edited by setting bool and int to true and 0 respectively)

Comment: You did not initialize variable notnumber.

Comment: ^ yes, it's never set `true` anywhere.

Comment: Student name is: Assylbek uulu Kadyrbek 
Student ID is:

Comment: I just now set it to true, and here is another output, some problem with id array still

Comment: What do you think the value of `i` is here? `int i; for (i; nameid[i]!='\0'; i++) {`. You need to add `=0`, if you want `i` to be zero.

Comment: If you have changed your question please make sure that you still show a [mre] which demonstrates the problem, describe the problem in detail, provide the input which triggers the misbehaviour, show the result/output you get, the output you want and describe the difference between them.

Comment: Please replace magic numbers like 48 with the character you mean.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Rule of thumb in C++: Always intialize variables with a reasonable value.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things I spotted in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int getNameAndID(char nameid[]) {
    char name[50];
    char id[50];
    bool notnumber;
    int i;
    for (i; nameid[i]!='\0'; i++) { // <---- (1)
        if (nameid[i] >= 48 && nameid[i] <= 57) {
            notnumber = false;
        }
        if (notnumber) { // <---- (2)
            name[i] = nameid[i];
        }
        else if (!notnumber) {
            id[i] = nameid[i];
        }
        
    }
    cout << "Student name is: " << name;
    cout << "\nStudent ID is: " << id;
    // <---- (3)
}
int main() {
    cout << "Enter the student information: ";
    char a[50];
    cin.getline(a, 50);
    getNameAndID(a);

}
```

**(1)** `i` is never initialized, which invokes undefined behavior by accessing `nameid[i]`.

**(2)** `name[i] = nameid[i];` This does not append `nameid[i]` on `name[i]`, (same applies for `id[i] = nameid[i];`). Consider the following:

```
index:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
nameid: hello world 1 2 3 4
id:     ? ? ? ? ? ? 1 2 3 4
```

There will be a portion of uninitialized values at the beginning of `id`. keeping a separate index for `id` for assignment should do what you want.

**(3)** No value is returned in `int getNameAndID()`, which also invokes undefined behavior.

Since you're using C++ not C, You'll make your life a lot easier by using `std::string`, you might want to do something similar to this:

```
void getNameAndID(string info) {
    string name, id;
    bool noDigit = true;
    for (auto c : info) {
        noDigit &= !isdigit(c);
        if (noDigit)
            name += c;
        else id += c;
    }
    cout << "Student name is: " << name << '\n';
    cout << "Student ID is: " << id;
}
int main() {
    cout << "Enter the student information: ";
    string info;
    getline(cin, info);
    getNameAndID(info);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot! I just started c++ so don't know some things which u showed, but now I got it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep different indices for `name` and `id`, in addition to the index used to traverse the input array `nameid`.
Increment each char array's index after inserting a character and at the end remember to add null terminators.

`i` needs to be initialized to zero.

Comment: Thank you, bro! I understand where are my mistakes